# Error in building WSO2 Platform 4.1.7

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-esb

I successfully built WSO2 **Orbit & Kernel 4.2.0** under JDK 1.6.x and Maven 3.0.5. But when I tried to build WSO2 **Platform 4.1.7** it shows

```
`Non-resolvable parent POM for org.wso2.carbon:integration:4.1.0:`
```

So tried building each sub folder from platform in the order.

1. parent,  dependencies,  service-stubs,  components,  features. 
   All got built successfully but

   samples/shopping-cart & samples/shopping-cart-global/2.0.0 threw errors.

So I skipped this and went to build the patches. but the very first patch 4.1.1 throws error

```
 WSO2 Platform Automated Suite - Distribution ...... FAILURE [40.549s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Patch releases - Platform Automated Test Suite  SKIPPED  

 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project wso2pats: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.wso2.carbon.automation:wso2pats:jar:1.1.1:
 The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.wso2.carbon.automation:org.wso2.carbon.automation.test.repo:jar:1.1.0, org.wso2.am:org.wso2.carbon.am.test:jar:tests:1.4.0:
 Could not find artifact org.wso2.carbon.automation:org.wso2.carbon.automation.test.repo:jar:1.1.0 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: If you are building 4.1.7 patch release, you need to build 4.1.0 (not 4.2.0) version of the orbit, kernel and all patch release related to kernel.

Comment: could u please tell me which platform version should I use, if wanna build from orbit and kernel 4.2.0 please ???

Comment: Tell me what is the product you need to build ? Refer WSO2 product release matrix (http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/). From this you can find corresponding kernel, orbit and chunk release numbers.

Comment: 1, I downloaded orbit and kernel 4.1.0 bot got built successfully. I  did not get any patch folder when downloaded kernel
2, when I built platform 4.1.7 it shows following error.

Comment: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/manoj/Manoj/Work/WSO2/Source/carbon/platform 4.1.7). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException